# Best instructions for null scenario in String approach

Tags: java, string, if-statement, null, equals

I want to hear opinions and arguments on this topic, I'm pretty undecided.

The equals method is the best one for value equality/testing?

```
if ("text".equals(testString))
```

Comment: 3 and 4 have redundant information and are longer, 1 will null pointer exception, so 2 is the best option.

Comment: And, if you sure myString will never be a null, 1 will work pretty good along with 2

Comment: By editing this question you make your accepted answer difficult to understand an learn from. Please undo your edit, or at least put back the four choices, in the same order.

Comment: Please refrain from editing your question in a manner that would invalidate an answer or make it extremely difficult to determine if an answer is valid only for some earlier version of a question. Additionally, this site considers a question to be off topic if it asks for or demands an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 4 may cause an `NPE` since `myString` may be null.

Number 3 could also throw an NPE because the expected return is an integer meaning, less than, greater than, or equal too.  If the passed argument is null, there would be no basis to return any of those as it would be misleading and any one would be a good as the other.  So the best option would be to throw an `NPE`.

For number 2, the equals test is a binary test so it is either equal or not.
"test" is used as a reference to equals, so using it will not throw an NPE.  In that case, the argument to the equals is `myString`.  A good equals implementation will first check if the argument is null before using it.  Therefore, no `NPE` will be thrown.

Comment: Can you tell me why 2 is not generating NPE? when myString=null, 1,3,4  generates NPE except 2

Comment: I undestand, but in(3) compareTo method myString is passed as an arugment too, but NPE is thrown, why?

Comment: @AndrewZ I modifed my answer with a better explanation.

Comment: My problem with this is the implication that a NPE is always bad. It just depends on whether the passed string can be `null` or not. If it should never be `null`, you really want that NPE because it tells you that there is something wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code and its output, only approach 2 will work .

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String myString = "test";
        String myString2 = null;


        if (myString.equals("test"))
        {
            System.out.println("Approach 1: myString.equals(\"test\") :Working if myString is not null");
        }
        if ("test".equals(myString))
        {
            if ("test".equals(myString2))
            {
                //This line wont execute
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Approach 2: \"test\".equals(myString) :Working even if myString is null");
            }
        }
        if ("test".compareTo(myString) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Approach 3: \"test\".compareTo(myString) == 0 :Working if myStrig is not null");
        }
        if (myString.compareTo("test") == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Approach 4: myString.compareTo(\"test\") == 0 :Working if myString is not null");
        }
        try
        {
            if (myString2.equals("test"))
            {
                //This will never execute
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Approach 1: myString2.equals(\"test\")  wont work if myString is null");
        }

        try
        {
            if ("test".compareTo(myString2) == 0)
            {
                //This line wont execute
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Approach 3: \"test\".compareTo(myString2)  wont work if myString is null");
        }
        try
        {
            if (myString2.compareTo("test") == 0)
            {
                //This line wont execute
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Approach 4: myString2.compareTo(\"test\")  wont work if myString is null");
        }
    }
}
```

The reason 1 and 4 wont work because in both cases input string is null .
For Approach 3 , it is expecting Not Null value please see implementation of compareTo function .

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
        int len1 = value.length;
        int len2 = anotherString.value.length;
        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;

        int k = 0;
        while (k < lim) {
            char c1 = v1[k];
            char c2 = v2[k];
            if (c1 != c2) {
                return c1 - c2;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return len1 - len2;
    }
```